# Using MySQL "NOT IN" but allowing for substrings

Tags: mysql

I am trying to query for rows that are not in another set of rows. However, the other set of rows may contain strings that include strings from the first table.

I'm confusing myself trying to explain so I'll use the following example  tables:

```
mysql> DESCRIBE tablea;
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| name       | char(40) | NO   | PRI |         |       | 
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+

mysql> DESCRIBE tableb;
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| nametag    | char(40) | NO   | PRI |         |       | 
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+

mysql> SELECT name FROM tablea;
+------------+
| name       |
+------------+
| cat        |
| dog        |
| cow        |
+------------+

mysql> SELECT nametag FROM tableb;
+------------+
| nametag    |
+------------+
| wolf       |
| dog        |
| browncow   |
+------------+
```

I am trying to find a method similar to the NOT IN operation, however because **cow** is "in" **browncow**, I also want to exclude this value.

```
mysql> SELECT name FROM tablea WHERE name NOT IN ( SELECT nametag FROM tableb );
+------------+
| name       |
+------------+
| cat        |
| cow        |
+------------+
# I am looking for something that would only return "cat" for this example.
```

Is there any operation where I can search for rows that aren't contained in another set with additional modifiers?

Comment: You could something with NOT LIKE CONCAT('%', name ,'%'), but I'm not sure how you would do that generically for all rows.

Comment: Also, if there is any volume of data, this is a terrible idea, as you are completely defeating your indexes.

Comment: @CargoMeister, I looked into the `CONCAT` documentation and I don't think I can do this for all rows either. And agreed that this is a bad idea for large datasets! My actual dataset would be quite small (rowcount<10).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an anti-join pattern, with a LIKE predicate to do the matching. (The anti-join is an outer join, to return *all* the rows from one table, along with matches from another table, and then a predicate to *exclude* the rows that had a match

```
  SELECT a.name
    FROM tablea a
    JOIN tableb b
      ON b.nametag LIKE CONCAT('%',a.name,'%')
   WHERE b.nametag IS NULL
```

(Any rows from `a` that had a matching row from `b`... the row from `b` will have a non-NULL value. Or, to put it another way... rows from `a` that didn't have a matching row in `b` will have a NULL value for the columns from `b`.)

If there's a row in `a` that has `name='cow'`, and a row from `b` that has `nametag='browncow'`, those rows will match.

The row from `a` with `name='cat'` will only be returned if the string `'cat'` doesn't appear in any values of `b.nametag`.

**NOTE**: The percent and underscore characters are wildcards in the `LIKE` predicate. If you want to do matching on those characters, you'd need to "escape" those with a backslash. There's similar issues using a `REGEXP` match, but a lot more possible mischievous characters.

---

There are other query patterns that will return an equivalent result.

For example:

```
  SELECT a.name
    FROM tablea a
   WHERE NOT EXISTS 
         ( SELECT 1
             FROM tableb b
            WHERE b.nametag LIKE CONCAT('%',a.name,'%')
         )
```

Personally, I prefer the anti-join pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Use "NOT EXISTS" along with INSTR

```
select *
  from tablea a
 where not exists(select 1 from tableb b where INSTR(a.name, b.nametag) > 0)
;
```

To exclude empty strings:

```
select *
  from tablea a
 where not exists(select 1 from tableb b where INSTR(a.name, b.nametag) > 0)
   and length(a.name) > 0
;
```

Comment: Oh you want to EXCLUDE when they're similar...  Your question is worded confusingly.  In that case use LIKE.  Somebody already beat me to it.

Comment: I like this answer but it fails one of my edge cases where a.name is the empty string.

Comment: Empty strings exist in any string, and will probably match with nearly any query you write (including the concat/LIKE method).  So if you're trying to exclude them as well, you'll have to add an explicit exclusion.

Comment: I think the arguments of the `INSTR` function should be reversed to get the matching OP wants... to get `a.name='cow'` excluded by a match to `b.nametag='browncow'`... the predicate needs to be **`where INSTR(b.nametag,a.name)`**